# Get all ids of GROUP_CONCAT in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, group-concat

Table B

```
id   name     tablename
1    abc      table1    
2    xyz      table2
3    abc      table1
4    sdf      table2
5    dfg      table1
```

Query:

```
SELECT B.tablename, GROUP_CONCAT(B.id),GROUP_CONCAT(B.name||'-'||cnt)
FROM (
    SELECT tablename, id, name, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM B
    GROUP BY tablename,name
) B GROUP BY B.tablename
```

Output:

```
| tablename | GROUP_CONCAT(B.id) | GROUP_CONCAT(B.nameB||'-'||cnt) |
| ------ | ------------------ | ------------------------------- |
| table1 | 1,5                | abc-2,dfg-1                     |
| table2 | 2,4                | xyz-1,sdf-1                     |
```

But here i'm not getting full ids as you can see in output of table 1.

i want something like :

```
| tablename | GROUP_CONCAT(B.id) | GROUP_CONCAT(B.nameB||'-'||cnt) |
| ------ | ------------------ | ------------------------------- |
| table1 | 1,3,5              | abc-2,df-1                      |
| table2 | 2,4                | xyz-1,sdf-1                     |
```

Pls help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GROUP_CONCAT()` for the `id`s in the subquery also:

```
SELECT tablename, GROUP_CONCAT(id), GROUP_CONCAT(name||'-'||cnt)
FROM (
    SELECT tablename, GROUP_CONCAT(id) id, name, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM B
    GROUP BY tablename, name
) 
GROUP BY tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=86612940bf28008b05f13a9d6b10db9b).

Comment: Thank u so much. I totally new to this sqlite queries as i always worked on ORMs.